# Extract sub-text based on topics in the text using python(data cleaning/extracting/processing)

Tags: python, text, nlp, data-cleaning

Consider text1:

> What is Lorem Ipsum:
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
>
> Where does it come from:
> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
>
> Why do we use it:
> It is a long established fact that a reader will be
> distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.

text2:

> What is Lorem Ipsum:
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
>
> Other Topic:
> There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.
>
> Why do we use it:
> It is a long established fact that a reader will be
> distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.

text3:

> What is Lorem Ipsum:
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
>
> Where does it come from:
> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
>
> Some other topic:
> Various versions have evolved over the years.

I can process this text using python to extract between a starting and ending string. Code used by me -

```
# This code is run once separately for each text variation 
import sys
s = "text1 or text2 or text3" # one at a time
start_String = s.find("What is Lorem Ipsum:")
end_String = s.find("Why do we use it:")
if start_String == -1 or end_String == -1:
    print("Not found")
    sys.exit(0)
print(s[start_String:end_String])
```

But my requirement is something different.
I need text related to only "What is Lorem Ipsum:", "Where does it come from:", "Why do we use it:".

Results expected:
text1:

> What is Lorem Ipsum:
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
>
> Where does it come from:
> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
>
> Why do we use it:
> It is a long established fact that a reader will be
> distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.

text2:

> What is Lorem Ipsum:
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
>
> Why do we use it:
> It is a long established fact that a reader will be
> distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.

text3:

> What is Lorem Ipsum:
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
>
> Where does it come from:
> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.

I have text collection like the above in a huge dataset. All i need to do is extract only required sub-text based on necessary topics. How can i implement this in python? I hope i made sense.

Comment: Try `text1.split(":")[1:]`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal can you please explain more. should i apply this only on text1? How does it affect the processing?

Comment: if you want to process `text1` `text2` etc. one at a time you can simply replace `text1` by `text2` and so on. You can do this by saving all these individual strings in a list and then loop it over!!

Comment: Tried that. I did not get the results as expected. `text1.split(":")[1:]` just splits the text based on `:` and is creating a list of lists.  `s1 = "text1";
s2 = "text2";
s3 = "text3";
list_String = [];
list_String.append(s1);
list_String.append(s2);
list_String.append(s3);

newList = [];
for text in list_String:
    newList.append(text.split(":")[1:]);`

Comment: Can you give a sample output format ?

Comment: ['\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\n\nWhere does it come from', '\nContrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.\n\nWhy do we use it', '\nIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.']

Answer (score 0):

This gives exactly what you want:

```
my_list=["""What is Lorem Ipsum:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Where does it come from:
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.

Why do we use it:
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.""","""What is Lorem Ipsum:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Why do we use it:
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.""","""What is Lorem Ipsum:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

Where does it come from:
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text."""]


new_list =[]   ## Creating an empty list

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    new_list.extend(my_list[i].split(":"))
```

Comment: i am sorry but that is not the result what i am expecting. Please check the "Results expected:" portion of the question. Appreciate your efforts tough!